# Is Map.containsKey() useful in a Map that has no null values?

Tags: java, performance, hashmap

In the following piece of code:

```
if (map.containsKey(key)) {
    map.remove(key);
}
```

Looking at performance, is it useful to first do a `Map.containsKey()` check before trying to remove the value from the map?

Same question goes for retrieving values, is it useful to first do the contains check if you know that the map contains no `null` values?

```
if (map.containsKey(key)) {
    Object value = map.get(key);
}
```

Comment: The first example is redundant even in the presence of null keys.

Comment: Which JDK implementation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`remove`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#remove-java.lang.Object-) returns `null` if there's no mapping for `key` no exception will be thrown:

```
public V remove(Object key)
```

I don't see any reason to perform that `if` before trying to remove a `key`, perhaps maybe if you want to count how many items where removed from the map..

In the second example, you'll get `null` if the `key` doesn't exist. Whether to check or not, depends on your logic.

Try not to waste your time on thinking about performance, `containsKey` has [O(1) time complexity](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html):

> This implementation provides **constant-time** performance for the basic operations (`get` and `put`)

Answer (score 4):

> is it useful to first do a Map.containsKey() check before trying to remove the value from the map?

No, it is counterproductive:

- In the case when the item is not there, you would see no difference
- In the case when the item is there, you would end up with two look-ups.

If you want to remove the item unconditionally, simply call `map.remove(key)`.

> Same question goes for retrieving values

Same logic applies here. Of course you need to check the result for `null`, so in this case `if` stays there.

Note that this cleanup exercise is about readability first, and only then about performance. Accessing a map is a fast operation, so accessing it twice is unlikely to cause major performance issues except for some rather extreme cases. However, removing an extra conditional will make your code more readable, which is very important.

Answer (score 0):

The Java documentation on `remove()` states that it will remove the element only if the map contains such element. So the `contains()` check before `remove()` is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

This is subjective (and entirely a case of style), but for the case where you're retrieving a value, I prefer the `contains(key)` call to the null check. Boolean comparisons just feel better than null comparisons. I'd probably feel differently if `Map<K,V>.get(key)` returned `Optional<V>`.

Also, it's worth noting the "given no null keys" assertion is one that can be fairly hard to prove, depending on the type of the Map (which you might not even know). In general I think the redundant check on retrieval is (or maybe just *feels*) safer, just in case there's a mistake somewhere else (knocks on wood, checks for black cats, and avoids a ladder on the way out).

For the removal operation you're spot on. The check is useless.